# Iterative closest point algorithm

Tags: slam, lidar

I am working on an assignment to create SLAM without using ROS.
I have 2D lidar sensor data.

If I move the robot quickly using only odomatry, the map is generated distorted.

[image]
[image]

I would like to combine the above two images using the iterative closest point algorithm. But I don't understand that algorithm.
Please provide an easy code that implements the ICP algorithm in C++.